# Why my gerrit does not have hook subdirectory?

Tags: git, hook, gerrit

all
   I am using gerrit 2.12.2, I install it on my ubuntu-14.04, After configuration I want to make a test project. The push to remote need to commit-msg hook to generate commit-ids  automatically. But I can not find the hook directory on the gerrit server.

[image]

Why there is no directory named hook? and how can I get the commit-msg hook script?

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding from [this](https://git.eclipse.org/r/Documentation/user-changeid.html#creation) that Change-Ids are created at commit time on the client side, so no hook should be on the server.

Comment: But some online resolution of Change-id for gerrit  is  'scp' the 'commit-msg' hook to local from gerrit server.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

The commit-msg hook script is not downloaded from gerrit installation path. It can be downloaded with the URL composed of gerrit site base and "/tools/hooks/commit-msg".
So if your gerrit site path is  http://192.168.1.2, you can get this hook with

```
wget  http://192.168.1.2/tools/hooks/commit-msg
```

Comment: You don't have to construct it. When you try to push a commit wihout change-id to the Gerrit, it will tell you the whole command to execute in order to get the hook, including the URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is the full command to install the commit-msg hook in a local repository:

```
gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); curl --create-dirs -Lo ${gitdir}/hooks/commit-msg https://<gerrit-server>/tools/hooks/commit-msg; chmod u+x ${gitdir}/hooks/commit-msg
```